# What is the most compact or efficient way of doing several subsitutions in a file in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file data.base which looks like:

```
1234 XXXX
4321 XXXX
9884 ZZZZ
5454 YYYY
4311 YYYY
9882 ZZZZ
9976 ZZZZ
```

( ... random occurrences like this till 10000 lines)

I would like to create a file called data.case which derives from data.base just with substitutions of XXXX, YYYY, ZZZZ for float numbers.

I wonder what would be the most compact/efficient/short way to do that on bash or friends.

What I usually do is something like:

```
sed -e "s/XXXX/1.34555/g" data.base > temp1
sed -e "s/YYYY/2.985/g" temp1 > temp2
sed -e "s/ZZZZ/-4.3435/g" temp2 > data.case
rm -fr temp1 temp2
```

But I do not think this is the most compact or efficient way when you have to deal with more than 3 substitutions.

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of associative arrays in awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{
 # add as needed
 s["XXXX"]=1.3455
 s["YYYY"]=2.985
 s["ZZZZ"]=-4.3435
}
($2 in s) {  print $1,s[$2] }' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
1234 1.3455
4321 1.3455
9884 -4.3435
5454 2.985
4311 2.985
9882 -4.3435
9976 -4.3435
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an option to ececute several commands in same sed:

```
sed "s/XXXX/1.34555/g; s/YYYY/2.985/g"; s/ZZZZ/-4.3435/g" data.base > data.case
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat sedcommands
s/XXXX/1.34555/g
s/YYYY/2.985/g
s/ZZZZ/-4.3435/g
$ sed -f sedcommands data.base > data.case
```

Answer (score 0):

sed -e "s/XXXX/1.34555/g;s/YYYY/2.985/g;s/ZZZZ/-4.3435/g"

or put them in a cmd file
and list them out.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst `sed` can do multiple substitutions in one pass, ***the*** [general UNIX approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) which is more widely applicable and can be combined with other commands is to use command piping:

```
cat data.base | \
   sed -e "s/XXXX/1.34555/g" | \
   sed -e "s/YYYY/2.985/g" | \
   sed -e "s/ZZZZ/-4.3435/g" > data.base
```

The redirection at the end will '`unlink`' the old data.base that is being used as input by `cat`; you could however still use a temporary file so that you can intercept error conditions and not have lost the original data.base in the process.

(When using piping, its useful to be familiar with the `tee` program, which saves the stream to a file whilst passing it on)

Comment: its not necessary to pipe to 3 seds.